# Force RMIService to bind with specific IP address

Tags: binding, jboss, ip, registry, rmi

I implemented RMIService using Spring RMIServiceExporter running at port 4099. When I start my Jboss , RMI Service is getting bonded to 0.0.0.0:4099 instead of 127.0.0.1:4099. I tried different parameters

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost  
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost.localdomain along with
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true parameter. 
Started Jboss with -b 127.0.0.1
```

Its always getting bonded to `0.0.0.0:4099`. I check it using

```
>netstat -anp | grep 4099

>TCP    0.0.0.0:4099           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Here is my implementation:

```
    RmiServiceExporter rmiServiceExporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
    rmiServiceExporter.setService(this);
    rmiServiceExporter.setServiceName("MyService");
    rmiServiceExporter.setServiceInterface(MyServiceManager.class);
    rmiServiceExporter.setRegistryPort(4099);
    rmiServiceExporter.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `java.rmi.server.hostname` has nothing to do with setting the bind-address, and I'm not sure it has anything to do with Spring RMI either. It is a feature of the `java.rmi` package.
2. The listening port shown in the `netstat` output is the Registry port, not necessarily the port your server is listening on.

It appears you will have to define your own `RMIServerSocketFactory` that creates `ServerSockets` bound as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that to access RMI from another server, RMI service should be bonded as 127.0.0.1:4099 or 192.168.29.8:4099. I had this issue in the Linux server and it turns out that I have to open up the ports in "iptables".

Comment: You can only access 127.0.0.1 from within the same host.