# Java Server to get GET/POST HTTP request

Tags: java, http, server

I want to start a server on my own PC to get GET/POST HTML requests.

This is the java code I used:

```
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.sql.Date;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

    public class SimpleHTTPServer {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

            final ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4000);
            int number_req = 0;

            System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 4000 ....");
            while (true) {

                final Socket client = server.accept(); // Accepting connection
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (!line.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }

                // print number of request, date and time 
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                SimpleDateFormat formatTime = new SimpleDateFormat ("E dd.MM.yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a");
                Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                System.out.println("Number of requests: " + number_req + " \n\tin "+ formatTime.format(date));
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to send an HTML request from my browser web to my ip:port like this:

```
http://79.49.72.102:4000
```

but I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED always.
I tried with localhost:4000 and I received the request.
I also used No-IP and setted Port Forwarding on my router but nothing seems work.

What I've to do?

Comment: have you read anything about http protocol?

Comment: One other issues would be to force JAVA to bind to the network ip address. This post may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362627/force-rmiservice-to-bind-with-specific-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

Connection is refused because the server 79.49.72.102 does not permit you to connect on port 4000 using HTTP. This is a common security measure implemented through firewalls on the server.

Who owns 79.49.72.102?
It looks like a public address, so it will not accept random incoming connections on a non-standard port like 4000.

Comment: The address 79.49.72.102 is and example address of my network.

Comment: First run `ping 79.49.72.102` from your command line. If `ping` works, that means the address is valid, and it's the server that's blocking your request. So talk to the server administrator to open up access to the port for you.

Comment: Try running "telnet 79.49.72.102 4000"

Comment: With No-IP, I can do:  `code`ping myhost254.ddns.net`code` and the command works.

Comment: @MinhKieu `code`telnet myhost254.ddns.net 50500`code` doesn't work.

Comment: @MicheleLombardi - why 50500? your socket code was 4000? Also have you read this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362627/force-rmiservice-to-bind-with-specific-ip-address. You may need to force Java to bind to the ipaddress of the network card.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ServerSocket(port) will only bind to localhost.  Try this:

```
final ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4000, 0, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the IP address you tried to use is your routers IP. If you want to connect to your server over internet, you have to make port mapping in your router. Like `external_port -> local_ip:local_port`
In your case the `local_ip` local ip of computer where you have to run your serer, and `local_port` is `4000` as you write. And the `external port` can be what you want. 
Remember that after port mapping you will use you server over internet with your routers ip and the external port which you chose.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem adding the local ID address of my server pc into DMZ rules.
Everything go well.